# yeoman aspnet:mvccontroller generator scaffolding with model on OSx

Tags: asp.net-mvc, macos, visual-studio-code, yeoman, asp.net-core-1.0

Has anyone of you tried to generate MVC Controller with scaffolding based on model class using yeoman generator? I'm trying ASP.NET Core on OSx, using Visual Studio Code. 
On Windows+Visual Studio 2015 with MVC 6, screen for scaffolding a controller with model would look like screenshot I assume, but it's not there on OSx. [image]
When I use yo aspnet:mvccontroller ControllerClassName I get a controller but it doesn't create CRUD Views or db migration. Is there any other generator switch that I'm missing? I didn't find much information on yeoman.io including its github.

Any help is appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0):

I found out the way, its 1 command with multiple parameters.

dotnet aspnet-codegenerator --project /Users/coreapps/CoreWebApp2 controller --force --controllerName MoviesController --model CoreWebApp2.Models.Movie --dataContext CoreWebApp2.Data.ApplicationDbContext --relativeFolderPath Controllers --controllerNamespace CoreWebApp2.Controllers --useDefaultLayout